# Bash script + no module named numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash

I am trying to use a Python file in the terminal. I know this file runs when I use `python file.py` with no issues that I can see. However when I have a bash script that runs the same file it comes up with the error:

```
ImportError: No module named numpy
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Do you use any virtual environment? Do you run the file from the bash script with the same python(version)?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by virtual environment? How would I tell what version of Python the script is running.

Answer (score -1):

For me the issue was the way I've created and run the bash script.
You should know that there is a difference between shell and bash - practically bash is a superset of shell with more features and better syntax.
So when you create a bash (shell) script to execute your python you need to do the following:

1. Create your script `your_bash.sh` like this:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   python your_python.py
   ```
2. Make the script runnable

   ```
   chmod u+x your_bash.sh
   ```
3. Run the script

   ```
   ./your_bash.sh
   ```

Comment: There are differences between `sh` and `bash` but not in the commands you show.

Answer (score -1):

Check command on bash script and in console:

```
which python
```

Most likely they are different.